# How to avoid inserting duplicate values in the collection using db.insertMany() in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Query:

```
db.getCollection('parents').insertMany(
    [{
        'name': 'Mark',
        'children': 'No Childs'
    },{
        'name': 'Carl',
        'children': '2'
    }], {
      'ordered': true,
    }
)
```

I'm using mongoose as ORM

Can someone please suggest if we have any options like unique: true?
I want the content to be checked not the _id since it will never be duplicate

Note: I've tried findOneAndUpdate using upsert: true, but here I've to insert multiple docs at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While defining the model schema you can specify which field is unique for example:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{ 
  FieldName:{ 
             type: String, 
             unique:true 
            }
})
var UserModel = mongoose.Model('User',userSchema);
```

If you want just to add index there is

```
schema.index({FieldName1: 1, FieldName2: 1}, {unique: true});
```

[Or more details can be found here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

Answer (score 5):

As per the documentation if you have an unique index on a field (in your case `name`) and you are trying to insert multiple documents with [**insertMany**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) you will get an exception the moment an error occurs:

> Inserting a duplicate value for any key that is part of a unique
>   index, such as _id, throws an exception.

However if you set `'ordered': false` the execution of the insertMany would not stop and you would have those documents which **do not** conflict with the `unique` index inserted:

> With ordered to false, the insert operation would continue with any
>   remaining documents.

So setup an unique index on the `name` field and when you do `insertMany` [only those records which violate that index would be skipped](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#unordered-inserts).